# Why won't this div add a class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I make a `$.get` call to my db and it returns some HTML (`data`):

```
$.get(url, null, function(data) {
```

The HTML it returns is something like this:

```
<div id="1234" class="myclass">..more html..</div>
```

In my callback function, I try to add a class to it (based on some conditionals that I have tested are successfully being reached) like so:

```
if (someCondition) $(data).addClass('mynewclass' + someId);
```

Even when `someCondition` is true, my HTML is not having the `mynewclass[someId]` class added to it. Is there any reason why this may be that I'm just stupidly overlooking?

Thanks... :\

### **EDIT**

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/T4aUA/) to a reproducible example. It's not EXACTLY what i'm doing per se (i'm not using a var outside to get my data, but i'm reproducing the same effect). notice how it's showing 'false' for the test.

Comment: what is `someId` ?? Can u post a link to ur code

Comment: `someId` is the id of the model. but it's a number.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do w your problem, but fwiw ids should not start w numbers. It's not valid html.

Comment: @peter i am aware that ids shouldn't start w/numbers, but i also think it's not part of the problem. @garis, #1234 is the id of the model being rendered on the server. i use it to find this div to do other cool jquery stuff to it [edit: garis removed his comment].

Comment: I would post the actual code segment.  Are you using something like selector.append(mynewhtmlstring); ?
Note that the selector is on the "selector" in this one and you probably need .end()...type structure with the .addClass() after that new element is selected

Comment: is $(data) actually the div element returned? It might be better to construct it by the ID you get back like this: $('#' + yourReturnedID)

Comment: @mark i'm working on posting some code @moin `data` is raw html, yes the div.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example on jsbin or jsfiddle for us?

Comment: in your example you are creating two complete different DIVs from scratch and only attaching 1 to the dom. replace all uses of the variable 'data' with the string literal and you may see what I am talking about. Here is how this example would give the behavior you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/T4aUA/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are creating multiple div objects. The first one you are creating is being discarded. Then a new one is created which does not have the class that was previously added.

Hold on to a reference of the div that was first created and to which the class was applied. Then add that same div to the page.

```
function(something) {
    var div = $(data).addClass('someClass');
    $('#container').html(div + div.is('.someClass'));
}
```

However, now we are dealing with an object (`div`) and not a string, and trying to convert an object to a string will yield `"[object Object]"`. So modify the append function to this:

```
$('#container').empty();
$('#container').append(div).append(String(div.is('.someClass')));
```

[See your example updated](http://jsfiddle.net/T4aUA/3/).

Comment: +1 You were quicker than I was, although you would need to do `div.html() + div.is('.anotherclass')` so you don't get `[object Object]true`. EDIT: Actually, I'm not quite right on that since `.html()` only gives you content. Your update is correct. :o)

Comment: thanks @Patrick :) I realized that after actually running the code.

Comment: GOD I FEEL SO DUMB. thank you anurag. the part about setting my data to a local var solved the problem.

Comment: LOL we have all been there.  Some of the functionality of append rears it fully functional head :)

Comment: @Jason - the programmers brainfart is a common thing. don't worry about it, we've all been there and sometimes practically lived there :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery like raw javascript works on DOM. And what you are doing, is trying to manipulate on data( HTML as long string in your case). You need to atleast add HTML data you requested to DOM, before you start doing tricks with it. Your callback should be something like this..

```
function(data){
  $('#container_to_fit_data').html(data); // Adding to Document
  someId = 1234;
  if (someCondition) 
      $('#'+someId, '#container_to_fit_data').addClass('mynewclass' + someId);
      // or lets see it in simplest form
      // $('#container_to_fit_data').find('#'+someId).addClass('mynewclass' + someId);
}
```

**[ EDIT ]**

@Anurag Its true that jQuery is able to manipulate strings data, but its not true that its the case with non-ID transactions.

You can see,

```
DOM_STR1 = "<div>
              <p>
                 <strong>Strong</strong>
                 <span class='myclass'>Span</span>
              </p>
            </div>"

DOM_STR2 = "<p>
              <strong>Strong</strong>
              <span class='myclass'>Span</span>
            </p>"


$('span.myclass', DOM_STR1) // We find span. Allright.
$('span.myclass', DOM_STR2) // We find span. Cool.

$('p', DOM_STR1) // We find p too. But..
$('p', DOM_STR2) // Empty. Never return p, Why??
$('div', DOM_STR1) // Empty Again. Why??
```

'div' is present in DOM_STR1, same way 'p' is present in DOM_STR2. Why jQuery can't read the wrapping element, but finds children from string??

So, when data is anyway needed to be on DOM, it makes no sense to manipulate it from string.

Comment: That's not true. Only when dealing with id's, do we need to insert into the DOM. Otherwise, we can directly create and manipulate elements outside of the document perfectly fine - `$('<p>').addClass('someClass');`

Comment: re:your edit - if you simply call `$(DOM_STR1)` instead of `$('div', DOM_STR1)` you have access to the outer layer. my problem was that i was making changes to the object but not permanently. once i set it to a local var and made changes to that, everything was gravy

Answer (score 1):

@Jason: thats my point, you need to use .addClass on a jQuery object, not raw HTML. Or you need to pattern match 'data', treating it as a string (which it is) and inject your class into the class attribute.

Comment: when you wrap it in `$()` it becomes a jquery object

Comment: OP *is* using `.addClass()` on a jQuery object. `$(data)` is a jQuery object with the HTML string passed in and rendered into DOM elements. A jQuery object can accept raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The "data" variable refers to the entire collection of returned information. Something like this should work:

```
if(someCondition) { $(data).find('#1234').addClass('mynewclass'+someId); }
```

Comment: i thought of that, but doing that doesn't work. i tried a $(data).is('[a class already on it]') and it returns true, so i'm actually at the top of the tree

Comment: @simplyharsh yes it will. `$(data)` will turn it into a valid jquery object that you can manipulate. the trick is to set it to a local var so that the changes stick :)